# Getting the default Network Interface via Java

Tags: java, networking, java-8

I'm trying to find the default network interface for the current machine running this app through Java code.

Here is my method. I currently look for `eth0`. However, if I'm running it locally on my mac I might want to use `en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)`. Is there any way to cleanly resolve to the default network interface via Java.

```
private String getDefaultNetworkInterface() {
    try {
        final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> netifs = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while (netifs.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = netifs.nextElement();
            if (networkInterface.getName().toLowerCase().contains("eth0")) {
                return networkInterface.getName();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How do you define "the default network interface"?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the primary one, for example `eth0` or `en0`, whichever one is used for communicating with the outside world

Comment: In that case you need more information, namely the routing tables.  Look for the default gateway in the output from `netstat -rn` (or similar).  Note that this can get quite complex and also vary over time.  What is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: My app is trying to resolve to a single network interface to provide a bridge for multiple virtual machines to use. I noticed on some linux boxes its eth0 and on some developer macs its en0... so im just trying to build a method that resolves to the right one independent of environment

Comment: If you know the IP address of the machine then you can figure this out by walking the NetworkInterfaces...

Comment: The default interface depends on the destination network. if the networks `10.1.0.0/24`, `10.2.0.0/24`, and `10.3.0.0/24` are connected to three different interfaces, traffic destined to each network will have a different default interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the IP address of the current machine you can do something as below

```
        final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> netifs = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        // hostname is passed to your method
        InetAddress myAddr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);   


        while (netifs.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = netifs.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> inAddrs = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (inAddrs.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inAddr = inAddrs.nextElement();
                if (inAddr.equals(myAddr)) {
                    return networkInterface.getName();
                }


        }
```

Comment: And if you don’t have your `hostname`, or simply don’t want to care about it, use `InetAddress myAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();`

Answer (score 2):

What about this?  It finds the default interface which would successfully send traffic to the public internet.

```
private String getDefaultNetworkInterface() {
    // Find the default publicly routed network interface in the machine.
    // return null if we can't, otherwise its name.
    final String globalHost = "a.root-servers.net"; // Must exist.
    String name = null;
    InetAddress remoteAddress = null;

    try {
        // This requires we can do name resolution, if we can't we probably don't have
        // an interface thats publicly routed.
        remoteAddress = InetAddress.getByName(globalHost);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Log an error if you want.
    }

    if (remoteAddress != null) {
        try (DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket()) {
            // UDP does not actually open a connection, we just need to do this to get the
            // interface we would send packets on if we actually tried.
            s.connect(remoteAddress, 80);
            name = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(s.getLocalAddress()).getName();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // Log the error if you want.
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Effectively, it returns the first default interface that's facing internet. It's exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the brilliant idea.